Chained fiber bundles?
Is there any obstruction to having "chained" fiber bundles, in the sense that each fiber of the top level bundle is also the base space of a second bundle, with a different fiber?  Not considered in Steenrod so far as I can tell, nor have I seen it mentioned anywhere else. Perhaps possible in some specific situations such as fiber bundles of spheres?

It need not work, even for covering spaces. See this post.

Even easier, see Exercise 6 in Section 1.3 of Hatcher's Algebraic Topology.

Thanks Ted for the ref to the earlier post, which I missed somehow.  Looks like Ben McKay proved it for finite dim manifolds with smooth maps, a few years back, which is really a case I'm most interested in, even though the general case fails.
